# How to convey "to teach someone the ropes"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

The idiom *[to teach someone the ropes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/show-teach-sb-the-ropes)* means to teach someone how to do something, especially a job. E.g.

> "Jack has been here for years – he’ll show you the ropes."

Trying to convey the meaning in French I encountered *ficelles du métier*.

> Jack est ici depuis des années - il va te montrer les ficelles du métier.

Can one use colloquially the idiom *les ficelles du métier*? What other ways exist to convey the same meaning (in both formal and informal setting)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Apprendre les **ficelles du métier*** is a common suggestion to translate *to teach **the ropes***. The similarity between these metaphors likely helps. Both expressions refer to the demonstration of actual practice and not theoretical teaching.

There might be a slight nuance between them though.

To teach someone the ropes was originally telling an apprentice sailor which ropes was to be used to properly operate a sailboat.

On the other hand, the ***ficelles*** rather refer to tricks used to ease/simplify a job, like the hidden (invisible) strings a magician uses to hold something up in the air.

Unlike the ***cordages***, knowing how to use these "strings" can be but is not necessarily a best practice. That depends on what *ficelles* are being taught...

*Ficelles* can also be found in these expressions:

> ***Tirer sur les ficelles***: remotely handle things/people like a puppeteer.

> ***La ficelle était trop grosse***: the trick was too visible so it was discovered.

> ***Se débrouiller avec des bouts de ficelle***: getting by without sufficient means.

> ***Trop tirer sur la ficelle***: Ask for too much.

Comment: Thinking about it, one could even argue that the origin is different for the French version and actually refers to the same thing as "*tirer les ficelles*", in the puppet setting, meaning that the similarity between ropes and *ficelles* would be a coincidence. This is pure speculation of course.

Comment: @Reyedy I definitely think these *ficelles* are the same ones. That's what I'm refer to as *hidden strings*.

Comment: @Reyedy I mean *apprendre les ficelles* and *tirer les ficelles* refer to the same metaphor. *Ficelles* (strings) are not *cordages* (ropes).

Comment: @Reyedy — Que cela se fasse sans arrêt avec les écoutes et drisses des trois-mâts ou avec de la ficelle à rôti, l’art du matelotage est nécessaire et se transmet aux mousses comme aux apprentis.